# How to locate a file in windows explorer

Tags: winapi, file

I have a application to list all music files in user machine, a "Explorer" button is using to quickly open Windows Explorer and highlight the file in Windows Explorer. I tried ShellExecute, but it doesn't work, the API will launch associate application. Any Windows API can do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply start `explorer.exe` with the `/select` argument, as detailed [in this Knowledge Base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314853/en-us):

```
Explorer /select,C:\TestDir\TestApp.exe
```

Comment: Do you know the command line how to select mulit files by default

Answer (score 1):

You can [create an IE instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250462(VS.85).aspx) and navigate to your folder, then [query the IShellBrowser service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa770042(VS.85).aspx) from the top [level browser service](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257717) and get the active view's IShellView interface. Use IShellView::SelectItem to select items.

Remember to call IWebBrowser::Quit when you don't need the explorer window.

This method can not get around Windows Vista's User Interface Privilege Isolation. If the folder is opened in a process with a different integrity level, a broker IE extension is needed to continue the automation.